# vector cast vs array cast of derived object to base object

Tags: c++, casting

This is a question on a c++ assessment test. I don't understand why the vector cast is different than the array cast. Specifically, this outputs 1413. Why not 1414? Does the reference to &b in the x array declaration cause this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0) : m_n(n) { }

public:
    virtual int f() const { return m_n; }
    virtual ~A() { }

protected:
    int m_n;
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    B(int n = 0) : A(n) { }

public:
    virtual int f() const { return m_n + 1; }
};

int main()
{
    const A a(1);
    const B b(3);
    const A *x[2] = { &a, &b };
    typedef std::vector<A> V;
    V y({ a, b });
    V::const_iterator i = y.begin();

    std::cout << x[0]->f() << x[1]->f()
             << i->f() << (i + 1)->f() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no casts in your code, and the array stores pointers while the vector doesn't. If you use arrays and vectors that store the same type you will get the same results.

Comment: but the array that stores pointers is of type A while the vector that doesn't is of type A as well. So then why does the array of type A point to the b object? Why is this not resulting in slicing (as mentioned in the answer below)?

Comment: It doesn't result in slicing because the array is an array of *pointers*. When you created it, it doesn't  _copy_ the object. The vector actually stores instances of A, that you have to create by copying. If you had used `std::vector<A*>` everything would work. If you had used `const A x[2] = { a, b }` it wouldn't have.

Comment: @VarsMolta The vector vs array factor is completely irrelevant. This is the same issue as  `A* x = &b;` versus `A y = b;`. You would see this more clearly if you indexed the vector instead of using an iterator — `y[0].f()` works, but `y[0]->f()` won't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is noting what type of object is stored in the vector. You have a `typedef std::vector<A> V` which says this vector type only stores objects of type A (exclusively).

When you call the constructor, you passed in an object of type A and type B but the vector only knows of type A...so it does this (conceptually):

```
y.push_back( A( a ) )
y.push_back( A( b ) )
```

That's a copy-constructor call...which for type A automatically defined as `A( A const & )`. This allows you to create an object of type A out of an object of type B. In short, all your objects in the vector are of type A created from your other objects.

Answer (score 1):

`V y({ a, b })`copies `a` and `b` into the vector `y`. Because `y` is a vector of `A`, the `B` part of `b` gets lost during the copying process. This is called *slicing*.